# sylow $p$_groups in $S_6$

Tags: group-theory

We describe all the Sylow $p$-group in $S_6$:

a)shows that Sylow $2$-groups are isomorphic with $D_4$$\times$ $\mathbb{Z}$/$2\mathbb{Z}$  and that there are   $\dbinom{6}{2}$.3=45  such groups include !(hint:think of a Sylow $2$-groups together with permutation ($5$  $6$).

b)show dat the sylow $5$_groups isomorphic is met$\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ and the amount of them is $36$?

Answer (score 0):

a) Since  $6!=16\cdot 9\cdot 5$, we can simply exhibit a subgroup of order $16$ and have Sylow g2-roup. With $D_4\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ to aim for, we us $(5\,6)$ as $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. Can you exhibit a $D_4$ with permutations involving only $1,2,3,4$ (well, by definition of $D_4$, we can).
To count the Sylow 2-groups recall that they areconjugate to each other.

b) Same method. We know the order is $5$, hence it is cyclic, and we simply write down such a group, e.g. the one generated by $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)$. To count them: How many elements of this cycle pattern are there? How many of them generate the same subgroup?